# Creating new objects with Game Maker GML

Tags: game-maker

I'd like to know if there's a way to check if an object exists on a point, and if not, create a new one while snapping the new object to a grid? I know you can use this `instance_create(x,y,obj_to_create);` but that just places on a point no matter what and doesn't snap to a grid. Also, is there a global mouse click event in Game Maker?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a global mouse event, just put global_ in front of the mouse GML command you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are a few (almost similar) functions that allow you to do this... But most straight forward is to use `position_meeting(x,y, obj)`

so the could would become:

```
if (!position_meeting(x, y, obj_to_create)) {
    instance_create(x,y,obj_to_create);
}
```

Now to snap to grid you'll have to create it at a snapped position:

```
instance_create(x div GRIDW, y div GRIDH, obj_to_create);
```

Comment: Does this test if there IS something or if there ISN'T something at x, y? Also, do you know an answer to the "snap to grid" thing?

Comment: @Gordan you are asking a lot of questions at once...  Sorry type in the if statement - though a quick glance of that function with the manual should've yielded the solution. (updated now). As for snapping to grid: well that is something separate.....